# How to make the wordpress htaccess secure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How to make the wordpress htaccess secure.

Please help me about .htaccess -

1. Permissions.
2. Visibility.
3. Importance.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please have a look on how to ask a good question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I am always use WordFence security plugin. It's very useful. WordFence is one of the most popular WordPress security plugins. It keeps on checking your website for malware infection. If scans all the files of your WordPress core, theme and plugins. If it finds any kind of infection, it will notify you. It claims to make your WordPress website 50 times faster and secure. For making your website faster, it uses Falcom caching engine. This plugin is free, but a few advanced features are available for premium users. If you can afford it, do it.

Also, check this article http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/7-best-wordpress-security-plugins/

Comment: Thanks for the link, i dont use the plugins, if you can help me to provide the code so that i can implement that.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

**Permission:** 644 
**Visibility:** Since it's "."htaccess, it is hidden by default 
**Importance:** .htaccess is a web server config file for Apache. You get to set different config settings for your website through your .htaccess file; like 301 redirect, SEO-friendly URLs and so on.

Read more about it here: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is really very effective.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can protect the files by using this code:

> ```
> <Files login.php>
> AuthName "Prompt"
> AuthType Basic
> AuthUserFile /web/mywebsite.com/.htpasswd
> Require valid-user
> </Files>
> ```

2. Retrict its access and visibilty

> ```
> <Limit GET POST PUT>
> order deny,allow
> deny from all
> allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
> </Limit>
> ```

xx.xx.xx.xx is your IP.

3. Importance: 
   The .htaccess file is one of the core files that used to optimize the speed of your site, customize the WordPress, apply restrictions, redirecting rules,  can secure your WordPress site and many more